# Boot drive shows empty after reboot

Tags: boot, sd-card

I just inserted the SD card of my Raspberry Pi into the card reader and I added a `wpa_supplicant.conf` file because it was not connected to the internet.

However when I inserted the SD card in my Raspberry Pi it was not booting.

I inserted the SD card in the card reader and there was no Boot drive. Just Drive (H) that was empty and drive I which I cant access without format. I really need to get the data out of this sd. Any help?

Comment: the partition you "can't access" is the root partition which Windows can't read. As for the empty boot partition, that's a mystery. Which raspberry pi do you have? If it's a 3 plus or 4, you should be able to create a USB boot drive, then you can read the data on the root partition on the SD (if it hasn't also been erased)

Comment: Have you ever operated/used a Linux system? If so, plug your SD card into a USB-SD adapter [similar to this](https://www.walmart.com/ip/USB-card-reader-USB-3-0-Adapter-SD-Micro-SD-Card-Reader-for-Windows-Mac-Linux-and-Certain-Android/9697796580), and mount it. Then edit your question because we have virtually **nothing** to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

There is some third party tools for reading `ext` filesystem partitions. And theses should be able to access your data on the root partition on the SD-card.

[DiskInternals Linux Reader](https://DiskInternals%20Linux%20Reader)

[Ext2explore](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ext2read/) is old (2012) but is still working